# C++ or Python as a starting point into GUI programming?

Tags: c++, python, qt

I have neglected my programming skills since i left school and now i want to start a few things that are running around in my head. Qt would be the toolkit for me to use but i am undecided if i should use Python (looks to me like the easier to learn with a few general ideas about programming) or C++ (the thing to use with Qt).
In my school we learned the basics with Turbo Pascal, VB and a voluntary C course, though right now i only know a hint of all the things i learned back then.

Can you recommend me a way and a site or book (or two) that would bring me on that path (a perfect one would be one that teaches the language with help of the toolkit)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Being an expert in both C++ and Python, my mantra has long been "Python where I can, C++ where I must": Python is faster (in term of programmer productivity and development cycle) and easier, C++ can give that extra bit of power when I have to get close to the hardware or be extremely careful about every byte or machine cycle I spend. In your situation, I would recommend Python (and the many excellent books and URLs already recommended in other answers).

Answer (score 5):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt
You can use PyQT for Qt in Python.  They have recommendations for tutorials and references on there.

Google "How to learn Qt" and "Learning C++".
There are some decent sources on there.

Answer (score 4):

I have read [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt: The Definitive Guide to PyQt Programming by Mark Summerfield](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html) , it's cool.
for C++ : C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 (2nd Edition)
just my two cents.

Answer (score -1):

How about Ruby? You can write Qt apps in Ruby allegedly (http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum), and it gives you a good excuse to look at the very excellent "Why's Poignant Guide..." (http://poignantguide.net) which is how Monty Python would have introduced programming....

(Actually thinking about learning python myself, so feel free to ignore my advice (but visit Why's site anyway))

Comment: PyQT is far more mature than the Ruby port